# RxJS non-blocking pooling

Tags: node.js, typescript, amazon-web-services, rxjs

I'm working with Amazon Transcribe Service and in the SDK doesn't have any way to get when the transcription job has finished.

So we need to pool that information. Nowdays we have the following working code...

```js
const jobid = nanoid();

await amazonTrascribeClient
  .startTranscriptionJob({
    IdentifyMultipleLanguages: true,
    TranscriptionJobName: jobId,
    Media: {
      MediaFileUri: "s3://file-location",
    },
    Subtitles: {
      OutputStartIndex: 1,
      Formats: ["vtt", "srt"],
    },
    OutputBucketName: `file-location`,
    OutputKey: `transcriptions/${jobId}/`,
  })
  .promise();

// HELP HERE:
const callIntervalFunc = () => {
  const callInverval = setInterval(async () => {
    const { TranscriptionJob } = await amazonTrascribeClient
      .getTranscriptionJob({ TranscriptionJobName: jobId })
      .promise();

    if (
      ["COMPLETED", "FAILED"].includes(TranscriptionJob.TranscriptionJobStatus)
    ) {
      clearInterval(callInverval);

      // Persist in database etc...
    }
  }, 2000);
};

callIntervalFunc();
```

But as you can see it's extremally expensive and don't work in the concurrency mode since it's lock the thread. The objective is pool the information without block the event loop, some people said to use fire and forget, but I have no idea where I should start.

Comment: Use web workers if you don't want it to poll on the main thread

Comment: It's a backend code not running in browser.

Comment: I don't see how this is related to RxJS?

Comment: @TsvetanGanev I'm trying to rewrite the code using RxJS. Since it could react to the state change. I've saw some examples of pooling, but looks like they are blocking. I want to know how could I use RxJS for pooling in a non-blocking way.

Comment: You can't use it in a non-blocking way - the JS code execution is single-threaded and RxJS can't magically make it multi-threaded. You can see if https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html solve your issue. Also, why do you think Node.js can't handle your workload - isn't the processing done by the AWS servers anyway?